# Alterar cor conforme texto digitado na TextBox

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Olá!
Preciso de um código que altere o fundo de algumas TextBox assim que a página é carregada de acordo com o que foi "pego" do banco de dados, a minha idéia seria a seguinte: a textBox possui 2 valores possíveis = "ENVIADO" e "NAO ENVIADO", o código altera o fundo para Verde(ENVIADO) ou vermelho(NAO ENVIADO).
Não entendo muito de Javascript mas tentei esse e não houve sucesso:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ChangeColor() {
        var cor = document.getElementById("cxtexto");
    if (cor == "ENVIADO")
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "#FF4D00";
    else
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "#0a719c";
}
    </script>
```

De forma bem resumida a minha página PHP/html está da seguinte forma:

```
<html>
<body onload="ChangeColor()">
<head>
 **Aqui vem o Script citado acima**
</head>
<td>JANEIRO<input type='text' value='ENVIADO' id='cxtexto'></td>
<td>FEVEREIRO<input type='text' value='NAO ENVIADO' id='cxtexto'></td>
</body>
</html>
```

Os VALUES acima ele puxa do banco de dados (com PHP) mas supondo que fossem esses ai descritos, como seria?
Não encontrei mas se houver alguma pergunta parecida ou igual, poderia me passar o link?

Answer (score 0):

Primeira coisa é que não se deve usar o mesmo `id` em mais de um elemento. Se puder, altere `id="cxtexto"` para `class="cxtexto"` ou adicione um `class` igual para os campos.

Em seguida, você pode alterar as cores com `document.querySelectorAll`, percorrendo todos os `input text` e verificando o `value`:

```js
(function ChangeColor() {
   var cor = document.querySelectorAll('input.cxtexto');
   
   for(var x=0; x<cor.length; x++){
      cor[x].style.backgroundColor = cor[x].value == "ENVIADO" ? "#090" : "#F30";
   }
}())
```

```html
<td>JANEIRO<input type='text' value='ENVIADO' class='cxtexto'></td>
<td>FEVEREIRO<input type='text' value='NAO ENVIADO' class='cxtexto'></td>
```

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo :DD... sei não, acho que seu computador tah bugado.. aparecendo coisas que não existem

Comment: é vdd acho que é fome, vou almoçar :D

Comment: veja que se retirar da função, vai dar mesmo resultado

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Sim, mas como ele botou uma função na pergunta, acho melhor manter.

Answer (score 0):

Como já dito, não se deve usar elementos com mesmo id em um documento. Mas para a minha resposta isso pouco importa.

> `Já que está carregando a pagina de acordo com o que foi "pego" do banco de dados`, eu deixaria o PHP se encarregar de dar as cores aos inputs de acordo com os valores possíveis retornados, ou seja, `"ENVIADO" e "NAO ENVIADO"`.

Supondo que a tabela possui as colunas `mes` e `estado` com MySQLi ficaria assim:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

$sql=("SELECT * FROM tabela");
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while($fetch= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $corFundo = $fetch['estado'] == "ENVIADO" ? "#090" : "#F30";
    echo  "<td>".$fetch['mes']."<input type='text' value='".$fetch['estado']."' id='cxtexto' style='background-color: ".$corFundo."'></td>";
}
```